# How to import lodash in a typescript library package?

Tags: javascript, typescript, package.json, rollupjs

I'd like to centralize my generic most-used (typescript) functions in a Util package which I can reuse across my projects. Turned out more difficult than expected. This package is not going to be published, so I'm really only interested in ESM.

I was able to do this as a plain js-package, but now that I'm converting it to TS, I'm running into problems.

My question is, how to import from an external package? I use various Lodash functions. But Rollup complains that they don't exist, and/or have to be exported as well.

I've included the first function that I was putting into this lib, I'm very new to TS, so don't mind that too much. ;-)

```
[!] RollupError: "now" is not exported by "../../node_modules/.pnpm/lodash@4.17.21/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js", imported by "out-tsc/src/createUid.js".
https://rollupjs.org/troubleshooting/#error-name-is-not-exported-by-module
out-tsc/src/createUid.js (1:9)
1: import { now, random, padStart } from "lodash";
            ^
```

This my latests setup, going through many many variations:

---

*Config*

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "@vexna/util",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Generic utilities, uses lodash",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "sideEffects": false,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rimraf dist && tsc && rollup -c rollup.config.js",
    "test": "node test/spec",
    "pretest": "npm run build"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.12",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "@open-wc/building-rollup": "^2.2.1",
    "@rollup/plugin-babel": "^6.0.3",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^15.0.1",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.191",
    "deepmerge": "^4.3.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "rimraf": "^4.1.2",
    "rollup": "^3.12.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.21"
  },
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ]
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es2018",
      "module": "esnext",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "noEmitOnError": true,
      "lib": ["es2017"],
      "strict": true,  
      "esModuleInterop": false,
      "outDir": "out-tsc",
      "rootDir": "./",
      "skipLibCheck": true,
      "declaration": true,
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
    },
    "include": ["./src/**/*.ts"]
}
```

**rollup.config.js**

```
import merge from 'deepmerge';
import { createBasicConfig } from '@open-wc/building-rollup';

const baseConfig = createBasicConfig();
export default merge(baseConfig, {
    input: ['./out-tsc/src/index.js'],
    output: {
        format: "esm",
        exports: "named",
        dir: 'dist',
    },
    external: ['loadash'],
});
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
    "presets": [["@babel/env", { "modules": false }]]
}
```

---

*Code*

I've organised the code as follows:

```
/src
/src/index.ts
/src/createUid.ts
```

createUid is the first function that I was putting into this lib. I'd like to separate each function into its own file (but if they must all be in one file, that's fine too).

**createUid.ts**

```
import { now, random, padStart } from "lodash"

/**
 * Return a 16-digit unique integer based on the current time (ms) appended
 * with a three-digit random or provided number ("counter").
 * 
 * The id is an integer and consists of two parts:
 *   1) The number of miliseconds is a 13-digit number
 *   2) Appended with a three digit number, that is either:
 *      a) a left-padded number, if provided to the function
 *      b) a random numer
 * 
 * 1675246953915    February 1st, 2023 (today)
 * 9999999999999    November 20th, 2286
 * 9007199254740    June 5th, 2255
 * 9007199254740991 Max. safe integer
 *
 * Note:
 *  - This function won't work after November, 2286.
 *    If it is still in use then consider adding two instead of three digits,
 *    or use a bigint.
 * 
 */

const createUid = (counter?: number): (number|undefined) => {
    let p1 = now() // ms
    let p2 = ""
    
    if (counter == undefined) {
        p2 = padStart(random(0,999).toString(), 3, '0')
    } else if (isNaN(counter)) {
        p2 = padStart(random(0,999).toString(), 3, '0')
    } else {
        let carry = 0
        if (counter > 999) {
            counter = counter % 1000
            carry = Math.trunc(counter / 1000)
        }
        p2 = padStart(counter.toString(),3,'0')
        if (carry > 0) {
            p1 += carry
        }
    }

    // Create the integer
    const retVal = parseInt(`${p1}${p2}`)

    // Check if safe
    if (!Number.isSafeInteger(retVal)) {
        console.error(`Generated id is larger than safe integer ${Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER}.`)
        return
    }

    return retVal
}

export { createUid }
```

**index.ts**

```
export { createUid } from './createUid'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found <strike>two</strike> **three** possible working scenarios:

1. Use TSdx, the Zero-config CLI for TypeScript package development. https://tsdx.io/
2. Use lodash-es instead (but note that chains are not working in lodash-es!). Explanation below. This however still gives Jest errors when this library is imported in another library, and tested there.
3. Use `vitest` instead. Vitest is largely compatible with the Jest api. After installing Vitest, everything simply worked, without any configuration. The only thing to do is to add `import { assert, expect, test } from 'vitest'` to your tests. If you have just started, and only have simple tests, they simply worked without any changes (YMMV).
   In addition, **both** lodash and lodash-es worked fine.

A better answer would include a scenario that uses "plain" lodash, or explains why lodash-es is actually a good thing. From what I'm reading in various posts is that lodash-es has several drawbacks (results in a larger bundle size, chains don't work).

Here is a working setup with (I think) sensible defaults. This library is for internal use, and I run Node 18, so I use a high target version here.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "@vexna/util",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Generic utilities, uses lodash",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "sideEffects": false,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rimraf dist && tsc && rollup -c rollup.config.js",
    "test": "node test/spec",
    "pretest": "npm run build"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^11.0.0",
    "@types/lodash-es": "^4.17.6",
    "lodash-es": "^4.17.21",
    "rimraf": "^4.1.2",
    "rollup": "^3.12.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5"
  },
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "peerDependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.21"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.ts**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "es2022",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "declaration": true,
      "sourceMap": true,
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
      "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
      "lib": ["es2022", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
      "target": "es2022",
      "skipLibCheck": true,
      "strict": true,
      "exactOptionalPropertyTypes": true,
      "noImplicitAny": true,
      "noImplicitThis": true,
      "checkJs": true
    },
    "include": ["./src/**/*.ts"]
}
```

**rollup.config.js**

```
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript'
const input = ["src/index.ts"]

export default [
    {
        input,
        plugins: [
            typescript()],
        output: [
            {
                dir: "dist",
                sourcemap: true,
            }
        ],
        external: ['lodash-es'],
    }
]
```

The output has lodash entirely externalized, so very small bundle! As a precaution, I added "lodash": "^4.17.21" to the "peerDependencies". This is a little odd cause it's a mismatch with devDependencies (which uses the -es), but this seems fine. YMMV.

In the library code, you can import the lodash functions like so:

```
import { now, random, padStart } from "lodash-es"
```

A project that consumes this library must have lodash, and can import like so:

```
import { createUid } from '@vexna/util'
```